# Bad Request error while querying data from bigquery in a loop

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I am querying data from bigquery using get_data_from_bq method mentioned below in a loop:

```
def get_data_from_bq(product_ids):
    format_strings = ','.join([("\"" + str(_id) + "\"") for _id in product_ids])
    query = "select productId, eventType, count(*) as count from [xyz:xyz.abc] where productId in (" + format_strings + ") and eventTime > CAST(\"" + time_thresh +"\" as DATETIME) group by eventType, productId order by productId;"
    query_job = bigquery_client.query(query, job_config=job_config)
    return query_job.result()
```

While for the first query(iteration) data returned is correct, all the subsequent queries are throwing the below-mentioned exception

```
    results = query_job.result()
  File "/home/ishank/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job.py", line 2415, in result
    super(QueryJob, self).result(timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/ishank/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job.py", line 660, in result
    return super(_AsyncJob, self).result(timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/ishank/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/api_core/future/polling.py", line 120, in result
    raise self._exception
google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Cannot explicitly modify anonymous table xyz:_bf4dfedaed165b3ee62d8a9efa.anon1db6c519_b4ff_dbc67c17659f
```

Edit 1:
Below is a sample query which is throwing the above exception. Also, this is running smoothly in bigquery console.

```
select productId, eventType, count(*) as count from [xyz:xyz.abc] where productId in ("168561","175936","161684","161681","161686") and eventTime > CAST("2018-05-30 11:21:19" as DATETIME) group by eventType, productId order by productId;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the exact same issue. The problem is not the query itself, it's that you are most likely reusing the same `QueryJobConfig`. When you perform a query, unless you set a `destination`, BigQuery stores the result in an anonymous table which is stated in the `QueryJobConfig` object. If you reuse this configuration, BigQuery tries to store the new result in the same anonymous table, hence the error.
I don't particularly like this behaviour, to be honest.

You should rewrite your code like that:

```
def get_data_from_bq(product_ids):
    format_strings = ','.join([("\"" + str(_id) + "\"") for _id in product_ids])
    query = "select productId, eventType, count(*) as count from [xyz:xyz.abc] where productId in (" + format_strings + ") and eventTime > CAST(\"" + time_thresh +"\" as DATETIME) group by eventType, productId order by productId;"
    query_job = bigquery_client.query(query, job_config=QueryJobConfig())
    return query_job.result()
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Edited:

Federico Bertola is correct on the solution and the temporary table that is written to by BigQuery [see this link](http://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bigquery/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJobConfig.html#google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJobConfig).

I did not get an error with my sample code querying from a public table last time, but I can reproduce the error today, so it is possible this symptom can appear intermittent. I can confirm the error is resolved with Federico’s suggestion.

---

You can get the “super(QueryJob, self).result(timeout=timeout)” error when the query string lacks quotes around the parameters in the query. It seems you have made a similar mistake with the parameter format_strings in your query. You can fix this problem by ensuring there is quotes escaped around the parameter:

```
(" + myparam + ")
```

, should be written as

```
(\"" + myparam + "\")
```

You should examine your query string where you use parameters, and start with a simpler query such as

```
select productId, eventType, count(*) as count from `xyz:xyz.abc`
```

, and grow your query as you go.

For the record, here is what worked for me:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()
job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()

def get_data_from_bq(myparam):  
    query = "SELECT word, SUM(word_count) as count FROM `publicdata.samples.shakespeare` WHERE word IN (\""+myparam+"\") GROUP BY word;"
    query_job = client.query(query, job_config=job_config) 
    return query_job.result()

mypar = "raisin"
x = 1
while (x<9):
    iterator = get_data_from_bq(mypar)
    print "==%d iteration==" % x
    x += 1
```

Comment: Please consider using proper [query parameters](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries) instead of modifying the text of the query, too :)

Comment: I am adding quotes with escape characters while creating format_strings. Tried your solution too, It's not working. I have added a sample query which is throwing this error.

Comment: Tried your sample code too. It's throwing the same exception on 2nd iteration.

Comment: As Elliott pointed out, using query parameters is recommended. You can use this with the standard SQL syntax.

You mentioned you tried my sample code querying from a public table, but it is throwing the same exception. I suspect there is a problem with your setup. In your error text I see “annonymous table xyz”, but in your query, your table is named ‘abc’ not ‘xyz’. 

Confirm you have the table ‘abc’ under the dataset ‘xyz’ in BigQuery, and run a simpler query in your method to confirm your setup is fine: 

query = """select productId, eventType, count(*) as count from `xyz.xyz.abc`;"""